# Utilising Images in IntelliJ

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea

I've been developing a poker game for side project to introduce myself into using images and GUI development with IntelliJ and java in general. I'm now at a stage where I want to assign a image to an individual card from a collection of card images I have on my desktop.

Is there any concrete resource available about adding my folder of images to some sort other folder within the project itself so that I can load these straight from the project rather than from the desktop. Also, how would one assign these images?

currently I have a card class that builds itself from 2 Enum classes which store SUIT and another that stores RANK(values).

Card card = new Card(EnumSuit suit, EnumRank rank, "need to apply image in this part)

Apologies if my explanation is bad and thanks for any help!

Edit: I've tried using BufferedImage and ImageIO but it's difficult to wrap my head around having to load from the desktop each time.

Comment: are you using swing/swt? is it a web application?

Comment: I'm using swing and awt for my project, it's not a web application no. Just an offline game that runs on the local dekstop

Comment: If you use Maven and its standard directory structure you can load images from the CLASSPATH by adding the files to the src/main/resources folder.

Comment: Unfortunately I am just using a standard java project, i've just read up the documentation on Maven but didn't use that route. I'm not sure if i've left it too late to start adding images to my project then? I've got a fully functioning Poker game with an interface that just displays the toString of each card on the screen rather than the image I wanted to use.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write some code to cache these; reading the entire PNG or JPG in everytime you create a card object is going to make things noticably slow. I'm going to assume that EnumSuit and EnumRank (sidenote: Bad names; proper names are CardSuit and CardRank or even just Suit and Rank; your editor can tell you they are enums, you don't have to name things that way. You didn't name it ClassCard either :P)

Example code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.image.ImageIO;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Card {
  private static final Map<String, BufferedImage> imageCache = new HashMap<>();

  public static BufferedImage getImage(CardRank rank, CardSuit suit) {
     String k = rank.toString() + suit.toString();
     return imageCache.computeIfAbsent(k, k -> loadImage(k));
  }

  private static BufferedImage loadImage(String key) {
    try {
      return ImageIO.read(Card.class.getResource("cardImages/" + key + ".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Missing card image: " + key + ".png");
      System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
      // Return a blank image instead.
      return new BufferedImage(100, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }
  }
}
```

The above code caches your images (getImage uses the cache, loadImage always loads from disk, which is why it is marked `private`). Note, it uses the `MyClassName.class.getResource` mechanism, which looks for the provided file in the same location as where the VM finds the file `MyClassName.class`.

So, if you have this:

`C:\MyProjects\card_exercise\src\Card.java`

and your IDE, maven, gradle, ant, or whatever you're using to compile it ends up making the class file be here:

`C:\MyProjects\card_exercise\bin\Card.class`

then the above snippet will look for, say, '4A.png' in:

`C:\MyProjects\card_exercise\bin\cardImages\4A.png`

because it looks relative to the location where `Card.class` is located.

This mechanism (`x.class.getResource`) works even if you create a jar file with your classes and images combined together. Note that eclipse will copy non-java files straight from src to bin, and in maven, anything put in the 'resource' directory gets moved over during maven builds too.

Comment: Wow, that's an extensive answer I was hoping for. You sir are a saint, I'll study what you have suggested and try and put this into use. Thank you for your suggestion with the naming convention, just to be clear it doesn't matter if the
public enum EnumRank has "EnumRank" in the name of the enum? I was under the impression it needed to be, but now I think about it I can name a class anything so I guess the same would apply.

Comment: enums can have any name. Convention says YouShouldWriteItLikeSo (camelcased and starting with a capital), but other than that, anything goes. 'Enum' does not need to be in the name.